# I want to transfer media files from one device to another usinf wifi direct

Tags: android

I want to transfer media files from one device to another using wifi direct and i also want to include voice chat using wifi signal. I am able to send image files using wifi direct so I would like to know that how to proceed with video transfer.

Answer (score 0):

A video file is a file like any other. So in order to transmit a file, you need to read its bytes, put them in packets and transfer them. So I assume that you implemented WiFiDirectDemo project that allows sending an image. In the FileTransferService, you should have something like this in order to send a file:

```
   File myFile = new File (FILE_TO_SEND);
   byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [(int)myFile.length()];
   fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
   bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
   bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
   os = sock.getOutputStream();
   os.write(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
   os.flush();
```